# How to measure elapsed time between sending a message on a socket and sending it on the physical medium?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, timestamp, clock, nic

I need to accurately measure the time elapsed between calling sendto() in application layer and sending the last bit of the message on the wire in PHY layer. How can I measure this time in my C program? 
Thanks in advance.

------------------UPDATE--------------------

I found that some NICs are capable of [hardwqare timestamping](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt). So, I can measure sending time at application layer using host MONOTONIC clock and packet egress time using NIC timestamp. Now, the problem is finding accurate relation between host clock and NIC clcok :).

Comment: Hmm you probably can't, without writing a kernel module.

Comment: You might have some luck with `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/*`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Dear Marco, my original program is in user-mode. Is it possible for an external kernel module to measure this time?

Comment: You can approximate this pretty easily using eBPF (it sits right above the driver). Write an eBPF filter that records the time stamp of a packet, record the time you send the packet in userspace and then compare it to the filter result.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What exactly do you need this level of accuracy for?  There probably better ways to solve what you *really* want to do.

Comment: @dbush Sorry if it is not clear. I'm trying to write a paper and I need to measure latency components between two machines which are connected together via ethernet. This latency includes kernel processing time, read/write time, and link delay. I'm wondering if there is an approach to measure these components separately?

Comment: @LiamKelly can eBPF measure the time when a packet is sent on wire or it just measure the time packet is sent to NIC?

Comment: @shahriar If you're looking to measure round trip time, 1) have the sender put the current timestamp in a message 2) when the receiver gets it, note the current time and save the timestamp in the message 3) just before sending a response, the receiver subtracts the current time from the received time and adds the result to the sender's timestamp 4) send the modified timestamp back 5) sender gets the response, RTT is current time - timestamp in response.

Comment: @shahriar to approximate time on wire you need either: 1) two points of observation (left pc A at 12:00:00 got to pc B at 12:00:03) or round trip data (ping left at 12:00:00, got back at 12:00:06). The mechanism you use to get the timestamp is what your looking for, specifically something more accurate than userspace ( normal program). eBPF can get you a timestamp before the device driver to the NIC,so _almost_ right before it is sent to or received from the NIC.

Comment: Dear dbush, your solution works for RTT estimation. But, as i said, I need to measure delay components separately. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @LiamKelly, I guess your solution needs tight synchronization between 2 PCs. I updated the question and I believe hardware time-stamping may be the solution.

Comment: @shahriar, NTP is pretty accurate for what you are measuring. You could even run PTP for higher time resolution.